# chrome in offline mode/open cached site?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, browser-cache

I have a special kiosk-solution with chrome where I need chrome to upon application start, load the start-url from cache, not try to fetch it online.

The reason is that this is, like I said, a kiosk-mode presentation, is is a screen standing in the public that reboots every night, and if the reboot happens while the ISP has downtime on the internet connection, chrome will only show an error page.

If I can get it to load the cached version of the page though, instead of trying to fetch it online, then the last valid version of the page will show, and through some nifty ajax-workings of mine ;) it will automatically update after a while. If THAT update fails, the currently displayed version of the page will remain until a subsequent update succeeds.

See my problem?

In a browser like firefox I could do it by starting the browser in off-line mode and after page load switch it to online-mode. Only FF doesn't work for me in the particulat project, and Chrome doesn't seem to have an off-line mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [HTML5 Offline Web Applications](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/) to accomplish that. It's probably very easy to set up in your case, just add a file like the following to your app's directory:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
index.html
help.html
style/default.css
images/logo.png
images/backgound.png

NETWORK:
server.cgi
```

This manifest should contain all the files you'll need to display some useful information and later grab current content via AJAX. There's also a NETWORK section, where you have to specify things that should not be cached (ie the script that delivers your Updates via AJAX).

You can load the manifest file by adding a manifest attribute to your  tag (`cache-manifest` is the name of the file above):

```
<html manifest="cache-manifest">
```

Make sure your server delivers the cache manifest with a MIME-type of

```
text/cache-manifest MIME
```

Comment: Thanks, although the content that is fetched with ajax is what I actually want to cache, and keep showing until new content could be fetched, which then in turn replaces the last ajax-fetched content...

Answer (score 0):

Type or copy-paste the below flag setting into the chrome address bar.

**chrome://flags/#enable-offline-mode**

scroll down to **enable offline stale mode**.

**Restart** your browser.

If an offline version of the page is available in the system cache it will load up when you are not connected.